# How do I setup access to the SQL Server Membership and Role Providers from a Class Library?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

I have a client that wants to wrap the provider model with a middleware library, thereby keeping all Security.Web namespaces and API calls out of the front end completely.

Setting up calls into the API is easy. But configuring an app.config file is not quite as intuitive. I've not been able to find a good example.

What's the proper way to setup an app.config file for ASP.NET provider model use from outside a web project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `<system.web>` tag to be wrapped around the provider information. DOH!

Everything works like a charm now. Sorry for the snipe hunt.  ;)